# Integral of the function min{x,y}

Tags: calculus, probability

How do you integrate this:
$$\int_{-\infty}^1\int_{0}^\infty c\min\{x,y\}dxdy$$

I need to integrate this expression in order to find $c$.

(I saw some examples about how to integrate the function $\min\{x,y\}$ but none of those goes to infinity.)

Comment: Notice that for each given $y$, $\min\{x,y\} = y$ for $x \geq y$, and hence $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \min\{x,y\} \, dx = \begin{cases} \infty, & x > 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \\ -\infty, & x < 0 \end{cases}. $$ So the outer integral is even not well-defined unless $c = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you evaluate these expressions by splitting it up into domains where $x>y$ and $x\leq y$.

In this case the integral is equal to

$$I =\int_{-\infty}^1 \int_0^y c x\,\, dx dy + \int_{-\infty}^1 \int_y^{\infty} cy \,\,dx dy.$$

Unfortunately it seems like this is divergent unless $c=0$.

Comment: and what if it is a density function and has to be equal to 1?